# All Windows Live Messenger chat being emailed to me

Tags: windows-live-messenger, hotmail, windows-live

So for some reason I'm receiving emails from the person I'm chatting with containing the chat log of the last several lines of the conversation. This has happened with 2 different people only since I only just got on my laptop. But I noticed the email from the first while at work then when I chatted with my other friend when I got home. I'm logged in with a @msn.com address so it is a Live ID.

Does anyone have any idea what's wrong?

Comment: Are you sure you are not using an third party client ? I was using Trillian So what i noticed that every message you dont reply to you get the message emailed to you.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the Windows Live Messenger I downloaded from get.live.com is the official application.

Comment: Let me look more into it!